# Coin at the edge of the pocket

Tags: carrom

A coin was very close to falling into the pocket (let's say 70-30 over the edge). It stayed there for some time.

In one of the plays the striker hit the edge of the board so hard that the coin fell into the pocket (the striker never touched the coin or anywhere near the coin). The colour of the coin was same as the player's coin colour.

What should happen to the coin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official ICF rules:

> 71) If a C/m resting perilously at the mouth of the pocket and
>   actually falls into the pocket for any reason, it shall be considered
>   to have been properly pocketed.

[source](https://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm)

So the coin is pocketed.